# Highest concentration of a character within shortest possible substring

Tags: python, string, indexing, substring, slice

Let's say I have a very long string that goes something like this:

```
s = '-----1---------1----2----------4----------------1--------------2---------2--3------1---3------ and so on'
```

I know that in order to find the shortest possible substring containing all four different characters *(1, 2, 3, and 4)*, I have to write something like this:

```
s = "-----1---------1----2----------4----------------1--------------2---------2--3------1---3------"

seqs = []
for i, c in enumerate(s):
    if c in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
        seq = ""
        nums = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
        for c2 in s[i:]:
            seq += c2
            if c2 in nums:
                nums.remove(c2)
                if len(nums) == 0:
                    seqs.append(seq)
                    break

print(min(seqs, key=len))
```

But what if I want to find the shortest substring with the highest concentration of, say, the character `'1'`? I'm trying to think off of what I already have, but it feels like there's no way to know where to stop while iterating.

Comment: "with the highest concentration of, say, the character '1'" - Please define "highest concentration".

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, where there are the most 1s

Comment: any one 1 has a 100% concentration of 1s, can you be more specific about what you mean by "highest concentration"?